# Canvas turns blank when calling director.setDisplayStats(false); to hide FPS counter

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, cocos2d-html5

I'm new to Cocos2d-HTML5, but think I'm getting the basics well enough. However, while following [this tutorial](http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2013/05/16/from-zero-to-a-complete-game-with-cocos2d-html5-step-1/), I'm hitting a weird snag. Since I'm using Cocos2d-HTML5 v2.2.1, I updated the **cocos2dApp** class declaration as described in the comment section, and everything works fine.

But when I try to remove the FPS counter by using **director.setDisplayStats(false)**, or just commenting out the **director.setDisplayStats(true)** line, the canvas goes totally black. The code is still running; console.log() statements added to the sprite objects are still getting called every frame. Also strange: adding a call to **director.setDisplayStats(false)** during a frame update does *not* result in a blank canvas.

So my question is, by leaving out **setDisplayStats** or setting it to false, am I somehow messing up the scene's layers or something? I've tried tracing my way through how the code is executed after that statement, and haven't found anything obvious yet.

Answer (score 0):

I change (in ccConfig.h)

```
#define CC_ENABLE_GL_STATE_CACHE 1
```

to

```
#define CC_ENABLE_GL_STATE_CACHE 0
```

It helps me to avoid the crash.

Comment: I'm assuming that's for the C++ version, not HTML5. The JS equivalent appears to be cc.ENABLE_GL_STATE_CACHE, but setting a value of 0 (or false) in my config section did not make any difference, unfortunately.